# How can I hide and show all elements in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many same div with same content like this in mypage:

```
<div> 
<p class="firstp" id="p1-1" class="hideblock"> default-hide-1 </p>

<p class="secondp" id="p1-2">  default-show-1 </p>
</div>

<div> 
<p class="firstp" id="p2-1" class="hideblock"> default-hide-2 </p>

<p class="secondp" id="p2-2"> default-show-2 </p>
</div>
```

.
    .
    .

If I click on p1-2, I want add hideblock all first p except p1-1 (for p1-1 remove hideblock)

-also same example:  if click on p2-2, hide all  first p except p2-1 (for p2-1 remove hideblock class)

I try do it by this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#p2-2").click(function(){
        $(".firstp").removeClass('hideblock').addClass('hideblock');
        $("p2-1").removeClass('hideblock');
        $(".secondp").removeClass('hideblock');
        $(this).addClass('hideblock');             
});
});
    });
```

});

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#p1-1, #p2-1").click(function(){      
      $( ".firstp" ).removeClass('hideblock');   
    });

    $("#p1-2").click(function(){
        //where id is not p1-1 and class contains firstp
      $( "p[id!='p1-1'][class~='firstp']").addClass('hideblock');   
    });

    $("#p2-2").click(function(){
        //where id is not p2-1 and class contains firstp
      $( "p[id!='p2-1'][class~='firstp']" ).addClass('hideblock');   
    });

 });
```

Comment: missing some behavior and scale-ability as well as using invalid selector

Comment: jQuery adds its own selectors to the standard CSS selectors.